# CakePHP Recursive Find Method

Tags: cakephp

In my CakePHP app, I have the following model association:

> Offer -> Order -> Coupon

Then, at `OffersController.php`, i need to write a find method to output
the number of coupons sold on each offer, assuming that some orders can have multiple coupons.

The problem is that I'm in the `OffersController`, so when I try to use `find('count')`, I just get the number of offer entries. I want to count the number of coupon entries.

I tried to do something like `$this->Offer->Order->Coupon->find('count')`, but it does not work.

I tried to use the ContainableHelper as well, but got into the same problem of counting the wrong entries.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the resulting SQL query to do some magic with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`. Try to add a field like this (untested):

```
$this->Offer->Order->Coupon->find(
     'all',
     array(
        // Generate a field that counts the coupons per Order
        'fields' => array(
            'COUNT(Coupon.id) AS coupon_count'
        ),
        // Only look at Orders for the given Offer
        'conditions' => array(
            'Order.offer_id' => $id
        ),
        // This is important: group by Order.
        'group' => ('Coupon.order_id')
     )
);
```

If your Order -> Coupon have a simple hasMany relationship, a more convenient approach would be to keep track of the existing Coupon count in every Order record using an extra `coupon_count` field and the [counterCache function.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) CakePHP can automatically update that counter field for you.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. I just did it a little different, using find('count') instead of find('all).